# Как повесить анимацию на переход фрагмента

Tags: java, android, xml, анимация

Есть код для переключения между фрагментами

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.navigation_feed:
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransactionFeed = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransactionFeed.replace(R.id.content, feed, "Feed");
        fragmentTransactionFeed.addToBackStack("addFeed");
        fragmentTransactionFeed.commit();
        return true;
    case R.id.navigation_messages:
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransactionMessages = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransactionMessages.replace(R.id.content, messages, "Messages");
        fragmentTransactionMessages.addToBackStack("addMessages");
        fragmentTransactionMessages.commit();
        return true;
    case R.id.navigation_notifications:
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransactionNotifications = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransactionNotifications.replace(R.id.content, notifications, "Messages");
        fragmentTransactionNotifications.addToBackStack("addMessages");
        fragmentTransactionNotifications.commit();
        return true;
    case R.id.navigation_profile:
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransactionProfile = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransactionProfile.replace(R.id.content, profile, "Profile");
        fragmentTransactionProfile.addToBackStack("addProfile");
        fragmentTransactionProfile.commit();
        return true;
}
```

Нужно на `replace()` поставить анимацию слайд направо, а на переход к предыдущему фрагменту в бэкстэке анимацию слайд налево.
Как реализовать?

Answer (score 3):

До метода `replace()` (важно!) попробуйте

```
fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.right_in, R.anim.left_out);
```

Или для support библиотеки

```
fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.right_in, R.anim.left_out, R.anim.in_from_left, R.anim.out_to_right);
```

right_in.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">  
  <translate 
      android:fromXDelta="100%p" 
      android:toXDelta="0" 
      android:duration="100"/>
</set>
```

left_out.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">  
  <translate 
      android:fromXDelta="0" 
      android:toXDelta="-100%p" 
      android:duration="100"/>
</set>
```

in_from_left.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate 
        android:duration="100"
        android:fromXDelta="-100.0%p"
        android:toXDelta="0.0%p" />
</set>
```

out_to_right.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate 
        android:duration="100" 
        android:fromXDelta="0.0%p" 
        android:toXDelta="100.0%p" />
</set>
```